# "@:" is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with MVC5 and Visual Studio 2017 community, and I am in my Razor cshtml view page and I am trying to use `@:`, but it does not recognize it.

I get this error:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: ":" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.**

```
<td>
    @:test
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
</td>
```

Comment: There's no reason for you to use `@:` when you're not *already* in a code block (`@{ ... }`). Why not simply `test`?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you're not in a code block, you're typing it inside HTML.

`@:` is used to include a content line inside a Razor code block. Example:

```
@if(name == "Mark") {
    @: Hello Mark
}
```

If you have a variable `test` and you're trying to print it out inside your HTML, then use `@` like this:

```
<td>
    @test
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
</td>
```